# How to use NSDL PAN(Permanent Account Number) number verification API in php

Tags: account, pan, permanent

NSDL APIS has Java sample code.

https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/TIN/JSP/security/DownloadCodesForOPV.jsp

Comment: what is the password for the zip file?

Comment: What is the password for the zip file?

Answer (score 0):

This API is compatible only for RBL
Bank’s internal business use.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this Pan Card Verification API, gives you all info about the PAN Card number you enter.

[Pan Card verification API](https://rapidapi.com/rahilkhan224/api/pan-card-verification-at-lowest-price)